# How to efficiently draw bent or curved lines or arrows with Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, drawing, line-art, bezier-curve

I always use the Line Tool to draw arrows (by setting an Arrowhead at the end), like this:

[image: Line Tool settings]

[image: straight arrow]

Is there also a quick and easy way to draw *bent* (arched) arrows, like this?

[image: curved arrow]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the **Line Tool**:

1. Select the **Line Tool** from the tool bar and make sure your layer is set to **Shape Layer**. Before you make the shape on the artboard, click the gear icon and choose which side of the line (Start or End) you'd like the arrowhead to be on.  You can also set the width and height of the arrow head by a percentage proportional to the line:

[image]

2. Draw the line:

[image]

3. With the Line Tool still selected, activate the Free Transform options (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and select the **Warp Mode** icon on the top options toolbar:

[image]

[image]

4. Select the warp shape from the **Warp Options** toolbar at the top of the workspace. For this example I chose the Arc shape to more closely achieve the answer to the question:

[image]
***Note:*** Finalizing this step (or hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>) will turn the live shape into a regular path.

### Final product:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much mate, photoshop is damn terrible, why wouldn't they allow to just draw an arrow straight away?

Comment: Note that your arrow must initially be drawn horizontally for this to work. If it's vertical and then you turn it horizontal, the arc will be in the wrong axis.

Answer (score 3):

If you are just using lines and attaching the arrow, use the pen tool to create the curved line. Then add the arrowhead as you have been.

Answer (score 3):

I prupose you to :

1. create a circle with the **"U"** tool
2. add an arrow
3. delete 3/4 of the circle
4. extend the line

[image]

As photoshop is not the best software to do that, you can also create the arrow in Illustrator, and copy/paste it on photoshop. You will be able you modify it with double clicking on the arrow's layer.

[image]

I hope it will help you.

Cheer,
jérémy.